# обработка дубликата формы

Tags: php, javascript

есть блок с таблицей

```
            <table class="clone" id="hidden_change_personal_data_address">
                <tr>
                    <td class="personal_area_block1 inner_block_left">        
                        <div class="">country</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="personal_area_block2">                          
                      <input type="text" name="new_country" id="new_data"  value="" />                            
                    </td>                 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner_block_left">        
                        <div class="">province state</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="personal_area_block2">
                      <input type="text" name="new_state" id="new_data"  value="" />                            
                    </td>                 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner_block_left">        
                        <div class="">city</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="personal_area_block2">
                      <input type="text" name="new_city" id="new_data" value="" />                          
                    </td>                 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="inner_block_left">        
                        <div class="">street</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="personal_area_block2">
                      <input type="text" name="new_street" id="new_data"  value="" />                            
                    </td>                 
                </tr>
       </table>
```

и есть кнопка, по клику которой, добавляется еще одна такая таблица на `js`. Но она создается по типу `clone` со всеми именами инпутов. Вопрос в том, где именно сменить функционал, т.к при обработке формы с одинаковыми именами полей - явно не вариант

Comment: Ну по идее и исходная таблица тоже не верна: у вас `id="new_data"` в четырех разных полях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - отправлять данные массивом:

```
<input type="text" name="new_country[]" id="new_data"  value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

@MarselArduanov, абсолютно прав. Если сделать форму массивом, то работать будет намного проще и при клонировании, и при дальнейшей обработке данных.

Если поменять на массив нельзя, то...

Если надо на чистом `JS`, то это довольно сложно...

На `JQuery` по-проще:
Вам надо созданный клон занести в переменную, обработать, и лишь потом вставлять на страницу.
Примерно так:

```
// клоним в переменную 'cl'
var cl = $('#hidden_change_personal_data_address').clone();
// внутри клона находим все элементы, в которых есть 'id' аттрибут
// переименовываем каждый. Переименовку сделаете как Вам надо по проекту
// тут мы добавляем '-1' к источнику
cl.find('[id]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '-1');
});
cl.attr('id', 'hidden_change_personal_data_address-1'); // не забываем поменять id у новой таблицы.
cl.insertAfter($('#hidden_change_personal_data_address')); // вставляем клон в текст
```

Тот же принцип можно применить и к аттрибуту `name`.